# How do I log in with a different account?

Tags: draw-something

My sister downloaded Draw Something on my phone. She thought she could log in as herself, play, then I could log in and play. Since she logged in first it will not let me log in. I have uninstalled app and reinstalled but it always pulls up her account.  This has gone on for months. She has it on her phone now and all her drawing drawings come up on my phone too.  I want to play too! How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried logging out by clicking on the cog in the top-right, then Account and then Log Out?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

On the top right of your screen there is an orance little options - wheel
Click on that and then tap the Account option.

Then scroll down and you will find a logout button.

Then you will be redirected to the main screen again and you will have to option to log in using either your email or a facebook account etc.

Comment: We have done that. Somehow her sisters account got attached to her Facebook account and we can not separate them. This happened with her old phone, now she has a new phone and we downloaded game and still same thing!

Comment: This game should really fix it's log in system...

Did you try logging out of your facebook application first?
Then go in drawsomething and log out and log in again WITHOUT using facebook. Just normal log in.